# Getting Error With Query Removing Column Label

Tags: google-sheets, label

This is my first question posted on the site so I will do my best.

I am running a query formula in Google Sheets and using a drop down to filter the dateset. However, I added a string within the formula to remove the sum label and now when I filter I get an error. I have pasted my formula below. Ultimately I am just needing the sum of the number of surgery cases based on the location.

```
=query(Data!$A$2:$R,"SELECT sum(B) WHERE L=39 label sum(B)''"&IF(C3="Indiana",""," AND (I) = ('"&C3&"') "))
```

Without adding that label sum(B) '' I can filter the results with my drop down without issue. Once I added it the only time my filter worked is when I have it filtered on Indiana which sums all the data.

Please let me know if any additional information is needed.

EDIT: So to clarify my equation. I am summing the case count for each case, which is 1, from column B on the data tab. Column L on the Data tab references the week #. In my equation I am wanting to sum only cases from week 39. Column I from the Data tab is the Hospital Name. Cell C3 is my drop down which lists Hospital 1, 2, etc. and Indiana which sums all the cases for the State.

Here is the formula that works for the drop down without the label function added.

```
=query(Data!$A$2:$R,"SELECT sum(B) WHERE L=39 "&IF(C3="Indiana",""," AND (I) = ('"&C3&"') "))
```

EDIT #2 Here is the test sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rjlrLwI6LcA2vGeoEqrzqg0VdTD5cpXUrv-s8A1Ze2Q/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks!

Comment: do you have any sheet you can share ? only with dummy data. Just because you are querying from A to R and also you have L=39, you could simplify that to anyone who wants to help you

Comment: I have edited my original post for more clarification. Please let me know if anyone has any other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a quick look, your syntax for `label` is wrong.

`Label` must follow the rest of your query like:

```
=query(Data!$A$2:$R,"SELECT sum(B) WHERE L=39 "&IF(C3="Indiana",""," AND (I) = ('"&C3&"')  label sum(B)'' "))
```

If still in need, please share a test sheet.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Appreciate everyone's help! This fixed the issue. I also had to keep label syntax at the original spot as well so that when I filtered on Indiana it removed the sum label.

Comment: I tried to upvote but I am too new to the site. Also, it seems the issue isn't fixed yet. I will provide a test sheet here in a few minutes so that people can see what I am seeing. Adding that label only will work now when filtering on other locations and not Indiana as a whole.

Comment: *"I will provide a test sheet here in a few minutes..."*. Will be a great help.

Comment: Please make your sheet public.

Comment: Should be public now

Comment: So what is the issue? Please meet me at your sheet.

Comment: I am at the sheet and have typed my issue.

Comment: If your question is answered please take the time and accept it.